# Is it possible to max-out Health, Shields, and Salts in Bioshock: Infinite?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Essentially, I'm wondering if it's possible to find enough flasks to maximize each of these attributes, or if you will actually need to pick and choose for how you want your build to be at the end of the game.

Comment: Good question. I wonder if there's a "new game+" mode.

Comment: IMHO it is impossible otherwise there will be achievement for that!

Comment: @Gmoneyrocks maybe in DLC ;) now it is impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. There are only 24 infusions in the game and you would need 30 to max out all three stats.

Sources:

- [PS3 Trophies](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/bioshock-infinite/193381-collectible-guide-all-voxophones-infusion-upgrades-sightseer-videos.html)
- [GamesRadar](http://www.gamesradar.com/bioshock-infinite-infusion-locations-guide/)
- [N4G](http://n4g.com/news/1220581/bioshock-infinite-all-collectible-locations-voxophones-infusion-upgrades-sightseer)

Comment: If you buy the season pass it gives you an additional five infusion bottles at the Blu Ribbon taking you up to 29.